# GIF data block formula

Tags: math, gif, animated-gif

In the GIF specification here:

http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt

It gives the clear-code formula of:

> 2** codesize

Mathematically speaking, what does the above formula mean?

Sorry, I had to re-open this question given that [2 to the power of 4](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090219235947AAhSbZV) is apparently 8, but the example given in the GIF specification states 16 as the answer to their formula:

> example if the code size indicated was 4 (image was 4 bits/pixel) the Clear code value would be 16 (10000 binary).

Comment: Wow, that is a great example of well-formated ascii document!

Comment: No really, 2 to the power of 4, even according to that link you gave is 16. 2**4 (or 2^4) = 2*2*2*2 = 4*2*2 = 8*2 = 16. Or 2*2*2*2 = (2*2)*(2*2) = 4*4 = 16. Any way you look at it 2 to the power of 4 is not 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means 2 raised to the power of `codesize`.  The `**` notation for exponentiation comes from FORTRAN, I believe.

Comment: I will add, it's a bit weird as they also used '^' to represent exponentiation earlier in the document.

Comment: Don't suppose you could re-look at the question? It doesn't seem to follow exponentiation.

Comment: I never knew that that came from FORTRAN.

Comment: @SSight3: I've just corrected you on that. I think you must have had a friday moment when you were doing the maths.

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I am... having one of those moments.